# Trying to run a composite GUI in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am learning how to use the Eclipse IDE and trying to run a composite built in Eclipse. However, I can't get it to run the GUI can anyone help? I know I need `public static void main(String[] args)`but what do I need to add to this method to get it to run correctly? Can anyone please help me.

```
package gui;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CCombo;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;

public class GUI extends Composite {

// Strings to use as list items
private static final String[] items = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" };

public Framework(Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, style);

    Combo comboBox= new Combo(this, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
    comboBox.setBounds(174, 36, 534, 20);
    comboBox.setItems(Algorithms);

    Label lblOut = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
    lblOut.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    lblOut.setBounds(38, 145, 534, 327);

    Button btnExit = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
    btnExit.setText("EXIT");
    btnExit.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
    btnExit.setBounds(591, 421, 166, 51);
    btnExit.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void checkSubclass() {
    // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Framework framework = new Framework(); 
    Composite c = new Composite(framework, SWT.NONE); 
}
}
```

I get an error on the line `Framework framework = new Framework();` as I need two arguments `parent, font`. Please help and explain I'm only a beginner of Java.

Comment: You should not mix AWT components along with Swing components.Virtually no one has used AWT directly for the last 25 years. Place your Swing components in a JPanel which is then placed in a Jframe, then display the JFrame.

Comment: @FredK This is SWT **not** AWT - completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` for an SWT program must always create the SWT Display and run the SWT event dispatch loop.

Controls such as `Composite` must be contained in a `Shell` control.

So your `main` might look like:

```java
public static void main(final String [] args)
{
  // Create the display
  Display display = new Display();
  try
   {
     // Create main shell
     Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);

     shell.setText("Shell Title");

     shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

     // Put framework in the shell
     new Framework(shell, SWT.NONE);

     // Open the shell
     shell.open();

     // Main event dispatch loop
     while (!shell.isDisposed())
      {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
          display.sleep();
      }
    }
  finally
   {
     // Clean up
     display.dispose();
   }
}
```